# Slow Filtering Method on DataGrid

Tags: c#, performance, wpf

Sometime ago I asked a question regarding a slow Filtering method for my `DataGrid`. Months later and I have a relatively quick method, though I am still looking to improve performance, especially when the user is deleting text from the SearchBox as this seems to slow down more than if the user is typing characters in.

**OnTypingIntoSearchBox**

```
private void OnSearchBoxTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ApplyFilter();
}
```

**ApplyFilter**

```
private void ApplyFilter()
{
    if (CurrentJobsCollectionView != null)
    {
        CurrentJobsCollectionView.Filter = FilterJobs;
    }
    UpdateJobCounter();
}
```

**FilterJobs**

```
    private bool FilterJobs(object o)
    {
        return FilterByCheckBox(o) && FilterByJobsSearchBox(o);
    }
```

**FilterByJobsSearchBox**

```
private bool FilterByJobsSearchBox(object o)
{
    try
    {
        var searchText = CharactersOnly(jobsSearchBox.Text);
        var job = o as JobModel;
        if (searchText == string.Empty)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (CompanyContains(job.JobReference, searchText.ToLower()) || 
                CompanyContains(job.CaseClient, searchText.ToLower()) || 
                CompanyContains(job.JobDescription, searchText.ToLower()) ||
                CompanyContains(job.JobNotes, searchText.ToLower()) ||
                CompanyContains(job.JobID.ToString(), searchText.ToLower()))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        var hEs = new HandleExceptionService();
        hEs.HandleException(ex.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

**FilterByCheckBox**

```
private bool FilterByCheckBox(object o)
{
    var today = DateTime.Today;
    criteria.Clear();

    if (yourJobsCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        criteria.Add(new Predicate<JobModel>(x => x.ITName == yourJobsCheckBox.Tag.ToString()));
    }

    if (adamJobsCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        criteria.Add(new Predicate<JobModel>(x => x.ITName == adamJobsCheckBox.Tag.ToString()));
    }

    if (chrisJobsCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        criteria.Add(new Predicate<JobModel>(x => x.ITName == chrisJobsCheckBox.Tag.ToString()));
    }

    if (danJobsCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        criteria.Add(new Predicate<JobModel>(x => x.ITName == danJobsCheckBox.Tag.ToString()));
    }

    if (emilyJobsCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        criteria.Add(new Predicate<JobModel>(x => x.ITName == emilyJobsCheckBox.Tag.ToString()));
    }

    if (kitJobsCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        criteria.Add(new Predicate<JobModel>(x => x.ITName == kitJobsCheckBox.Tag.ToString()));
    }

    if (mattJobsCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        criteria.Add(new Predicate<JobModel>(x => x.ITName == mattJobsCheckBox.Tag.ToString()));
    }

    if (unallocatedCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        criteria.Add(new Predicate<JobModel>(x => x.ITName == unallocatedCheckBox.Tag.ToString()));
    }

    if (_employees.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().All(c => Convert.ToBoolean(!c.IsChecked))) // If none are checked
    {
        currentJobsDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
        completedJobsDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
        archivedJobsDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
    }

    JobModel job = o as JobModel;
    bool isIn = true;
    if (criteria.Count() == 0)
        return isIn;
    isIn = criteria.Any(x => x(job));
    return isIn;
}
```

I hope that isn't too much code - apologies if it is. I'm essentially looking for anyway to improve the efficiency of this filtering method, either by the user searching through typing in text or by checking specific checkboxes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851545/wpfs-icollectionview-filter-with-large-sets-of-data

Comment: Where is `criteria` declared? I strongly doubt you actually need to explicitly `new` up the `Predicate<T>` delegate.

Comment: IMO the post would be easier to follow if you simply included the whole code-behind as a single code block. That code is all in the code-behind, right?

Comment: IIRC, the filter predicate is called for each item in the source collection.  The most obvious performance issue I see is that you are clearing and re-populating the criteria list every time the filter predicate is run.  Wouldn't it be more appropriate (and performant) to maintain that predicate list as the check boxes' check states change?

Comment: @Mat'sMug that code is all the code-behind of the filter methods yes. Dan I'm not quite sure what you mean by that, am I not maintaining it as the CheckBoxes states change already?

Comment: No, you're clearing and re-populating the entire predicate list every time a character is typed in that search box. Also... don't worry about posting "too much code", this isn't Stack Overflow ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Well damn that doesn't sound good. So how would you suggest preventing that? Surely it's necessary that a new predicate is added each time. For example if I was searching for "Mat's Mug", we'd start off by the user typing "M", then they get all items in the collection beginning with "M". Then "a" so we will get all items in the collection beginning with "Ma" and so on?

Comment: I think the entire approach isn't quite WPF-idiomatic. I'll try to spare an hour later today to review your code =)

Comment: @Mat'sMug No rush whatsoever, I would really appreciate that, thanks :).

Comment: @Mat'sMug If I read it right, it's even worse than that - entering a character causes the control to re-filter the list, and the predicates are re-populated for each item in the list as the filtering determines whether the item should be filtered-out or not.  In other words, if you have a list of 100 items, and you type a search term with 10 characters, it re-builds the predicates 1000 times.

Comment: @Mat'sMug No meaning to bug, but did you get a chance to look at my code at all? :)

Comment: I haven't, but what I meant to answer was something about a more MVVM approach, moving all that logic from the *View* and into a *ViewModel* - the searchbox could be bound to some `SearchText` VM property, and then the filtering logic would need to be reworked to no longer clear and repopulate all the time; checkboxes' `IsChecked` state would also be bound to VM properties, so you would have a grip on their state changing - if checkboxes don't change, there's no need to change the corresponding `criteria`.

Answer (score 2):

The end of your code...

> ```
> bool isIn = true;
> if (criteria.Count() == 0)
>     return isIn;
> isIn = criteria.Any(x => x(job));
> return isIn;
> ```

Looks really weird to me

Get rid of the boolean variable, you don't need it to return a true or false value from expressions that return a boolean.

Also, make this an if/else statement.

```
if (criteria.Count() == 0)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return criteria.Any(x => x(job));
}
```

You could also condense this to a single return statement using a ternary statement

```
return criteria.Count() == 0 ? true : criteria.Any(x => x(job));
```

or even a simple or conditional

```
return criteria.Count() == 0 || criteria.Any(x => x(job));
```

some would say that having the `==0` isn't very clean when you could instead write it like this

```
return !criteria.Any() || critera.Any(x =>  x(job));
```

---

On the other hand, in your `FilterByJobsSearchBox` method I would un-nest the if statement, it is indented in a way that isn't necessary and looks messy.

Something else that you should do to make this more dry, is to apply the `ToLower` method to the variable assignment instead of when you compare to see if the jobs contain the search text, I will show you what I mean

> ```
>     var searchText = CharactersOnly(jobsSearchBox.Text);
>     var job = o as JobModel;
>     if (searchText == string.Empty)
>     {
>         return true;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         if (CompanyContains(job.JobReference, searchText.ToLower()) || 
>             CompanyContains(job.CaseClient, searchText.ToLower()) || 
>             CompanyContains(job.JobDescription, searchText.ToLower()) ||
>             CompanyContains(job.JobNotes, searchText.ToLower()) ||
>             CompanyContains(job.JobID.ToString(), searchText.ToLower()))
>         {
>             return true;
>         }
>     }
>     return false;
> ```

Here is what it looks like when you do everything I mentioned above

```
var searchText = CharactersOnly(jobsSearchBox.Text).ToLower();
var job = o as JobModel;
if (searchText == string.Empty)
{
    return true;
}

if (CompanyContains(job.JobReference, searchText) || 
    CompanyContains(job.CaseClient, searchText) || 
    CompanyContains(job.JobDescription, searchText) ||
    CompanyContains(job.JobNotes, searchText) ||
    CompanyContains(job.JobID.ToString(), searchText))
{
    return true;
}

return false;
```

we could go a little further and make this one return statement as well, it will be a very long return statement....

```
var searchText = CharactersOnly(jobsSearchBox.Text).ToLower();
var job = o as JobModel;
return searchText == string.Empty 
    || CompanyContains(job.JobReference, searchText)
    || CompanyContains(job.CaseClient, searchText)  
    || CompanyContains(job.JobDescription, searchText) 
    || CompanyContains(job.JobNotes, searchText) 
    || CompanyContains(job.JobID.ToString(), searchText);
```

Comment: I think `return criteria.Count() == 0 ? true : criteria.Any(x => x(job));` can be written as `return !criteria.Any() || criteria.Any(x => x(job));`

Comment: Much better would be just `return criteria.Count == 0 || criteria.Any(x => x(job)` because `criteria` seems to be a `List<T>` hence checking the `Count` property instead of using the `IEnumerable.Count()` method is cleaner.